# Create/Setup Replica Set for Non-Sharded Mongodb Instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

We are planning to setup non-sharded MongoDB Instance on Amazon AWS.
As per my understanding we need MongoD setup on Primary and Secondary to forms as a replica set.
Please advice if we need MongoS,Config Server & Arbiters.

Regards

Comment: This question belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is for "programming" questions. DBA and server questions should be directed to other affiliate sites.

Comment: Have you gone thru this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: Please read the docs linked above. mongos and config servers are part of a sharded cluster and are not needed in a replica set. Arbiters are an optional component of replica sets that vote to elect primary but do not hold data; they increase the failure tolerance of the replica set without needing the resources of a data-bearing node.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.